# Deformation retract of $C^1$ into $W^{1+s,2}$

Tags: functional-analysis, algebraic-topology, calculus-of-variations, global-analysis

I am currently trying to apply Ljusternik-Schnirelman theory to a problem in geometric calculus of variations and have the following problem:
I consider an energy functional $\mathcal{E}$ on a submanifold $\mathcal{M}_s\subset W^{1+s,2}(I,\mathbb{R}^n)$ for some open interval $I$ and $s>\frac{1}{2}$ (Sobolev-Slobodeckij space). The latter space is compactly embedded into $C^1(I,\mathbb{R}^n)$. Now I can essentially define the same manifold $\mathcal{M}_1\subset C^1$, such that $\mathcal{M}_s\subset \mathcal{M}_1$.

I know the homotopy type of $\mathcal{M}_1$ and therefore know the LS-category, but I need to know the category of $M_s$. Because of the continuous embedding I know that $cat(\mathcal{M}_s,\mathcal{M}_1)\le cat(\mathcal{M}_1,\mathcal{M}_1)$ but I need equality to get a useful lower bound for the number of critical points of $\mathcal{E}$ on $\mathcal{M}_s$. So my question is the following:

Is there a deformation retract between $C^1$ and $W^{1+s,2}$, or more precisely between $\mathcal{M}_1$ and $\mathcal{M}_s$, that could allow me to use the knowledge about the homotopy type of $\mathcal{M}_1$ in my setting? Any result in that direction would be helpful.

Every help is much appreciated, and I thank you in advance.

Comment: Aren't $C^1$ and $W^{1+s, 2}$ vector spaces, and hence contractible?  And I don't think the question about $\mathcal{M}_1$ and $\mathcal{M}_s$ can be answered without knowing more about what they are.

Comment: Well you got me there. So both spaces are contractible, and that does that imply automatically, that $C^1$ also deformation retracts onto $W^{1+s,2}$?
Concerning the second part of your answer: I dont know either what it looks like exactly. I am trying to incorporate different side conditions of my variational problem and am experimenting a bit and dont know which to focus on yet. 
Thank you very much anyways.

Comment: So for 2 Banach spaces: $S_1$ and $S_2$ with continuous embedding $S_2\subset S_1$, you get a deformation retract of $S_1$ into $S_2$ since both are contractible.
Considering $M_1\subset S_1$ and $M_2=M_1\cap S_2$ it is not necessarily true, that $M_1$ deformation retracts onto $M_2$?

Comment: Well, there is at least a zigzag of deformation retractions joining $C^1$ and $W^{1+s,2}$ via $\{0\}$, but showing a single deformation retraction would require an additional argument.  Your second claim is false, even for finite-dimensional vector spaces: take for example $S_1 = \mathbb{R}^2$ and $S_2$ the $x$-axis, and let $M_1$ be the unit circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Then $M_1 \cap S_2$ is two points, which is not even homotopy equivalent to the circle.

Comment: Ok I see. So it's not so easy as I hoped for :D Thank you very much for your insight! It is very much appreciated!